# Error query cakephp with mongodb in localhost window

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, window, xampp, localhost

I has one problem, my source write by cakephp and use mongoDB, it work in hosting is good but with localhost in my computer use window os is not work:

1 json in host is:

```
{
  "user": "admin",
  "password": "...",
  "powers": {
   "1":".....",
   "2":".....",
  },
}
```

but in localhost is

```
{
  "user": "admin",
  "password": "...",
  "powers": [
    ".....",
    ".....",
  ],
}
```

when I query in localhost, I just received:

```
"admin"
```

in some other collection, when I query, I received:

```
array()
```

or

```
array(
    'Option' => array(
        'id' => null
    )
)
```

when I test query by a file php and not use cakephp then it work good. i has reinstall localhost with XAMPP it does not work, i install localhost manual but it does not work, i can not find the error.